# Unity2D: creating an enemy that shoots a bullet left and right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an enemy that shoots a bullet according to the direction he's going to (left and right patrol).
I'm using the bullet as a prefab and I'm not sure what the sqript should be for the bullet itself (the patrol and shooting conditions are working).

this is my code for the bullet itself as of right now:

```
public class EnemyBulletSqript : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Rigidbody2D rb;
   public float force;
   // Start is called before the first frame update
   void Start()
   {
       rb.velocity = transform.right * force;
   }
}
```

this is the code of my shoting condition (creation of bullet):

```
public GameObject bullet;
public Transform bulletPos;

private float timer;

private void Update()
{
    timer = timer + Time.deltaTime;

    if (timer > 2)
    {
        timer = 0;
        Shoot();
    }
}

void Shoot()
{
    Instantiate(bullet, bulletPos.position, bulletPos.rotation, transform.parent);
}
```

the bullet curently only goes right
it might be important to say I used the Brackeys tutorial `2D Shooting in Unity (Tutorial)`

Comment: correct because you wrote right * force..

Comment: any idea how to Implament it in a way that will aloow me to shoot both directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: OP updated their code..

You need to pass a direction to your EnemyBulletScript, as it is not taking in that parameter and you are hard-coding a 'Right' transformation int here.

Firstly, you'll want to setup the Bullet Script, so it takes in a direction in which you wish to send the projectile.

```
 public class EnemyBulletSqript : MonoBehaviour
    {
       public Rigidbody2D rb;
       public float force;

       //Store direction
       private Vector3 direction;
       
       //Set the direction
       public void setDirection(Vector3 direction)
       {
           direction = dir;
       }


       // Start is called before the first frame update
       void Start()
       {
           // Use the direction to set the velocity
           rb.velocity = direction * force;
       }
    }
```

Set the direction before initialising the projectile.

```
void Shoot()
{
    GameObject newBullet = Instantiate(bullet, bulletPos.position, bulletPos.rotation, transform.parent);
    
    // Determine the direction based on the enemy's local scale (flipX)
    Vector3 enemyScale = transform.parent.localScale;
    Vector3 bulletDirection = (enemyScale.x > 0) ? Vector3.right : Vector3.left;

    // Get the EnemyBulletScript component and set the direction
    EnemyBulletScript bulletScript = newBullet.GetComponent<EnemyBulletScript>();
    bulletScript.SetDirection(bulletDirection);
}
```

Comment: would you mind adressing my question again (I've added the Instantiation info)

Comment: Done, basically updated it so it passes in a direction now, when the bullet object is initialised, BugFinder was correct in you didn't pass an actual value through